# Getting OutOfGas Error when trying to call smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, error

I am running tests of my !ink smart contracts using `@727-ventures/typechain-polkadot` module.
But when I am running tests, sometimes getting OutOfGas Error.
The strange thing is that not all cases are failing.
I tried to put `gasLimit` manually but didn't work.
Here is the code for calling smart contract.

```typescript
const MAX_CALL_WEIGHT = new BN(5_000_000_000_000_000).isub(BN_ONE)
const PROOFSIZE = new BN(1_000_000_000)
const gasLimit = api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
  refTime: MAX_CALL_WEIGHT,
  proofSize: PROOFSIZE,
}) as WeightV2

const result = await contract.query.func(...args, { gasLimit })
const gasRequired = preview.gasRequired as WeightV2
const newGasLimit = api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', gasRequired) as WeightV2
const res = await contract.tx.func(...args, { gasLimit: newGasLimit })
```

This code is running well sometimes but getting error sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code you provided, couple of things needs to be modified:

1. The line

```
const gasRequired = preview.gasRequired as WeightV2
```

should probably be

```
const gasRequired = result.gasRequired as WeightV2
```

But that can be destructured as well.

2. As per the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.tx), you should also include `storageDeposit` in the options
3. Options should be the first parameter passed to the `.func` method

Also, you don't need to create the type again, as `result.gasRequired` should be of the correct type already.

So, something like this should work:

```typescript
const MAX_CALL_WEIGHT = new BN(5_000_000_000_000_000).isub(BN_ONE);
const PROOFSIZE = new BN(1_000_000_000);
const gasLimit = api?.registry.createType('WeightV2', {
  refTime: MAX_CALL_WEIGHT,
  proofSize: PROOFSIZE,
});
const storageDepositLimit = null;
const {storageDeposit, gasRequired} = await contract.query.func({ gasLimit, storageDepositLimit }, ...args);
const res = await contract.tx.func({ gasLimit: gasRequired, storageDepositLimit: storageDeposit }, ...args);
```

Comment: The query result only have value, gasRequired, gasConsumed value.
And I have set storageDepositLimit as null but the result was same.

Comment: What are the polkadot.js and typechain-polkadot versions you're using? 
And, maybe a silly question, but what account is signing the tx, and does it have enough funds to pay for gas?

Comment: The `typechain-polkadot` version is the latest, `v1.1.0`
And of course account has enough fund to run the tx.